# div wont apply class

Tags: html, css, class

Okay,this is weird..

```
<div id='content' class='clickable'>
```

class 'clickable' wont apply at all. I checked with different browsers on different PC-s and same results checked in source code from all these browsers and all this browsers see is

```
 <div id='content'>
```

Cleared cache on all of them tried again but still class won't apply.
I assume that I have made a stupid and simple mistake just I can't see it yet :D
Here is all of the code in this div.

```
<div id='midweb'>
<div id='midinweb'>
    <div id='search'><input type="text" name="search" id='searchfield'></div>
    <div id='sortThis'>
    <div id='content' class='clickable'><p class='thumb' style='background-image'></p><p class='title'>text</p><p class='text'>text</p></div>
    <div id='content'><p class='thumb' style='background-image'></p><p class='title'>text</p><p class='text'>text</p></div>
    <div id='content'><p class='thumb' style='background-image'></p><p class='title'>text</p><p class='text'>text</p></div>
    <div id='content'><p class='thumb' style='background-image'></p><p class='title'>text</p><p class='text'>text</p></div>
    <div id='content'><p class='thumb' style='background-image'></p><p class='title'>text</p><p class='text'>text</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I excluded the text from code because it looked like a mess xD (same goes for style)

This is the css

```
.clickable{
    height:150px;
}
```

In any case I think even without set up css browsers should detect the class even if it is empty. :S

Comment: it is applied. But isn't visible. Try adding `background-color`

Comment: The character used for attributes is `"`. Try changing your attributs, so it looks like `id="content"`.

Comment: Use Inspect Element in Chrome (or the equivalent in other browsers) and check the metrics shown under the Computed tab to see  if your class properties are being applied.

Comment: @Manu, both `'` and `"` are valid

Comment: It is working fine. Check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4aRPB/

Comment: You shouldn't use the same ID several times...

Comment: @AmitJoki I thought this is only valid for JavaScript. Cool, I learned something ;)

Comment: @Manu, it is. It works even without quotes, but isn't recommended

Comment: May be you made your modifications on certain html page and viewing on browser an old copy

Comment: With regard to attributes in HTML 5, single quotes, double quotes and omitting quotes altogether work: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attributes

Comment: Seriously invalid markup here. An ID is like your name/SS number. It identifies you as you and cannot be used for someone else. Remember this when assigning IDs to elements, they must be unique to each element. If you wish to assign the same one to multiple, use classes.

Comment: @AmitJoki Your first comment warrants being posted as the answer.

Comment: @davewatts, I've posted it ;)

Comment: I've upvoted it :-). @Morsus, if any of the answers have helped you should accept it.

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/89363785/Untitled.jpg

Comment: Got it..It was a glitch in javascript. Sorry to bother you all :S
But thanks a bunch guys anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

The class is getting applied but it isn't visible to you.

Try adding `background-color` so you'll notice that the class is being applied.

Like this:

```
.clickable{
    height:150px;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FYtVT/)